# If I connect through multiple users to Salesforce Bulk API, what counts toward API limit?

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, limits, bulk-api

As stated by the title, I'm not sure if, having a connected app, the API limit is reached based on my license or users (they come from different customers, so each user has his own license with his own salesforce instance, they are not related to eachother).

So for example:

1. **User A** connect their salesforce user to my service (through oauth2), then I use that salesforce user to upload some data.
2. **User B** does the same as the previous user (they use two completely different salesforce instances, they don't know each other at all and they are not related)

So, will MyConnectedApp API calls count be 2 (one for user A and one for user B) or User A API calls count will be 1 and User B API calls count will be 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API are counted per ORG so if user A & B are on different org then their API call will be counted for their respective org. API call are not counted per connected App or per user.